# Rails 3 ajax javascript rendering issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to issue a simple ajax request in a rails (3.0.3) view through a link_to.

```
<%= link_to "like", toggle_author_likes_path(current_author, post), :remote => true %>
```

The idea of this being that the action in LikesController#toggle will render some Javascript to alter the page after the request returns. Fairly straightforward stuff, right?

The issue I'm having is that the action seems to have trouble finding the right *.js.erb file. The relevant snippet in the LikesController#toggle action is:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
  format.js
end
```

When I try to issue this request, the action is executed, but the request responds with a `500 Internal Server Error`. The text of the error is:

```
Missing template likes/toggle with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}...
```

I have double and triple checked the placement of my _toggle.js.erb file and am sure I have named it right, and the contents are valid (although that's not important because it is never completed).

Just doing a regular GET without any fancy ajax on the js file returns the exact same error, so chances are good that the problem lies somewhere along the Rails rendering chain.

I won't include the rest of the method as is is quite verbose and I am confident that it does not factor into this particular problem, but if anybody thinks it is important, I'll post it.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Fixed the problem. It was my own stupid fault, I named the view like a partial, with an underscore before it. Removed, and the whole thing works perfectly. Idiot, idiot, idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate template called toggle.rjs  [This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs), while being slightly outdated, still explains what to put in the toggle.rjs file.